# JQuery DefinitelyTyped, typescript 1.4 and Webstorm error highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm, definitelytyped, typescript1.4

I update my jquery.d.ts definition file from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts but it generate a lot of error if I open it inside WebStorm IDE.

I found on internet that may be WebStorm compiler couldn't be up-to-date so I went on "Preference"->"Languages&Framework"->"Javascript"->"Node.js and NPM" and I update the typescript package to 1.4.1 but nothing changes, as soon as I open jquery.d.ts file WebStorm highlight a lot of error on it.

I also added jquery-DefinivelyTyped as an external library with no changes. I noticed that if I open this definition file from the "External Libraries" folder inside the project it doesn't highlight any error but if I copy this one in my project folder the errors show up again.

Any suggestion will be really appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webstorm 9 and IntelliJ 14 syntax analysis do not support Typescript 1.4 new features syntax right now.

This is fixed in dev and should be available soon: check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14151

(this does not prevent you from transpiling using 1.4.1 in any case)

**EDIT**
Available in Webstorm 10 EAP since yesterday: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/02/webstorm-10-eap-140-2753/

Comment: And if I want to use Webstorm 10 EAP do I have to install it separately from my WebStorm 9?(my concern is on a lot of plugin i have alredy installed, setting that i don't want to loose etc..)

Comment: On OSX, it is a separate install and you can actually run the two concurrently (on different projects obviously)

Comment: yes, of course i will! Last question: i see that if i use the 1.3.0 jquery.d.ts file from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped  i got no error highlight (all errors are caused by the "UNION" sintax that is not yet recognized by webstorm 9). As soon as Webstorm 10 become fully available my 9 version will be automatically updated too? Or will I need a brand new installation?

Comment: Your 9 version will be updated. Actually, what usually happens is that a new installation occurs but all your plugins are automatically re-installed for you.